# Odd results after first float entered

Tags: c++

I have created a program to take in float values until a non-number is entered. The program will then print the numbers entered like {n0,n1,...,}, as well as sum up the number entered and compute the average.

My problem is after n0 is printed out all the rest of the numbers being printed out are not matching the number entered.

Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ManagedArray
{
    float *elements;
    int numberOfElements;
public:
    ManagedArray(float *ele, int NOE) 
        : elements(ele), numberOfElements(NOE)
    {}
    ManagedArray() 
    { 
        elements = NULL, numberOfElements = 0;  //default constructor
    }
    int Size();
    float get(int index);
    void add(float value);
    ~ManagedArray(); // Destructor
    ManagedArray(ManagedArray & ma); // copy constructor
    void print(ManagedArray ma);

};

float ManagedArray::get(int index) { return elements[index]; }
int ManagedArray::Size() { return numberOfElements; };
void ManagedArray::add(float value) 
{
    float * biggerArray = new float[numberOfElements + 1];
    if (elements != NULL)
    {
        // copy the old elements into the biggerArray
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
        {
            biggerArray[i] = elements[i];
        }
        // the old array is not needed anymore, we have a better copy
        delete[] elements;
    }
    // point at the new array
    elements = biggerArray;
    numberOfElements = numberOfElements + 1;

    // put the new number into the last element of the array
    elements[numberOfElements - 1] = value;
}
ManagedArray::~ManagedArray() { delete[] elements; }
ManagedArray::ManagedArray(ManagedArray & ma)
{
    elements = new float[10]; // put here to get the number of input here
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) // put here to get the number of input here
{
    elements[i] = ma.elements[i];
}
numberOfElements = ma.numberOfElements;
}
void ManagedArray::print(ManagedArray ma)
{
    bool hasNumbers = ma.Size() > 0;
    if (hasNumbers) {
        // print the stored numbers
        cout << "Entered numbers: " << endl;
        cout << "{";
        for (int i = 0; i < ma.Size(); ++i)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                cout << ", ";
            }
            cout << ma.get(i);
        }
        cout << "}" << endl;

        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ma.Size(); ++i)
        {
            sum += ma.get(i);
        }
        cout << "total: " << sum << endl;
        cout << "average: " << (sum / ma.Size()) << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "no numbers entered." << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    ManagedArray mArray; // default constructor call for ManagedArray
    float userInput;
    bool addingNumbersToTheList;
    cout << "Keep entering numbers. Enter a non-number to stop." << endl;
    do
    {
        cin >> userInput;
        addingNumbersToTheList = !std::cin.fail();
        if (addingNumbersToTheList) {

            mArray.add(userInput);  
        }
    } while (addingNumbersToTheList);

    ManagedArray copy(mArray);
    // fix cin after intentionally breaking it above.
    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        while (std::cin.get() != '\n');
    }

    copy.print(copy); 
    copy.print(copy);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

So for instance I enter 1 , 2 , 3 , a 
the program would print out {1, -4.22017e+37, 2.89451e+31}

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong with this method?

EDIT: I have fixed the copy constructor. Can someone show me how I would replace
the number 10 with the total of numbers input? in:

```
elements = new float[10];
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
```

Comment: Q: What's this "ManagedArray" stuff?  Why aren't you just using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: @paulsm4: this a .NET thing. I suspect the problem is here but I don't know anything about .NET in C++...

Comment: instead of `do { cin >> userInput;
        addingNumbersToTheList = !std::cin.fail();
        if (addingNumbersToTheList) {...` you can `while(cin >> userInput){...}`

Comment: `ManagedArray::add` will create, copy, and delete  arrays for every entry. This is kind of painful. Recommend increasing the size by a larger number to reduce the overhead.

Comment: `mArray.print(mArray);` no point passing `mArray` into a method of an instance of `mArray`. `mArray` already knows who and what it is.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. This means I haven't successfully duplicated your test case. Odds are good that's because you have a bug in `print` and I don't. [mcve], please.

Comment: @user4581301 I am forced by my professor to do the program this way.  I can link the entire program to see if the error occurs.

Comment: There is a bug in code you have not shown us. I can offer no further help. Voting to close.

Comment: @user4581301 I have linked my print function. I cannot seem to find the error in it.

Comment: This can most certainly be resolved with some debugging. Just check the array contents at a few points in program to check, if the problem is related to the array contents or to the printing of results.

Comment: Oh and please show your constructor and destructor code... `void ManagedArray::print(ManagedArray ma)` is asking for trouble since you take the parameter by value.

Comment: @grek40 I have added in the code from the entire program along with comments for the constructors and destructor.

Comment: @grek40 I switched void ManagedArray::print(ManagedArray ma) to void ManagedArray::print(ManagedArray &ma) but am still receiving an error.

Comment: @Djee Maybe I'm blind but I don't see any .net stuff here, are you sure `ManagedArray` isn't a Dylan Essman thing? :D

Comment: Read your copy constructor carefully. Think about how many floats you're allocating and copying.

Comment: @molbdnilo would i change elements = new float; to
elements = new float[];?

Comment: as molbdnilo said, the copy constructor is definitely faulty and its the cause for the observed behavior.

Comment: @grek40 Thank you for the help, I will reassess the copy constructor.

Comment: @DylanEssman you say "I switched void ManagedArray::print(ManagedArray ma) to void ManagedArray::print(ManagedArray &ma) but am still receiving an error". It should be a different error now. Or more specifically, you didn't receive an error before, did you? You just got wrong outputs (which is different from an error)

Comment: @grek40 Yes, that is correct. I am not receiving an error. I am getting the wrong outputs.  Sorry for the confusion, been working on the for over 12 hours now :D

Comment: @grek40 I fixed the copy constructor. Now I am just trying to replace "10" with the actual size of numbers input into the program.

Comment: Writing `ma.numberOfElements` instead of `10` shouldn't be that hard

Comment: @DylanEssman You have no assignment operator, thus I can break this entire class with two lines of code.  Why do professors assign these things, when they know darn well no student will get it right?

Comment: @grek40 after a night of sleep, I see the answer to my question. Using the size function I created in the class.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to iterate through every possible number in the array with a for loop and an array.

```
elements = new float[ma.Size()];

for (int i = 0; i < ma.Size(); i++)
{
    elements[i] = ma.elements[i];
}
numberOfElements = ma.numberOfElements;
```